# Solve $\sec(x)=\tan(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been trying to do this problem:

Solve $$\sec(x)=\tan(x),\quad 0≤x<2π$$

I started by rewriting $\sec(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$.

I then rewrote $\tan(x)$ to get $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{\cos(x)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$
Therefore:

$$1=\sin(x)$$

$$x=\frac{π}{2}$$

However, this is not a solution to the original problem because both $y=\tan(x)$ and $y=\sec(x)$ have asymptotes as $x=\frac{π}{2}$

So where have I gone wrong, or are there no solutions?

If there are no solutions, how would I know (in other words, can we prove there are no solutions, or is $x=\frac{π}{2}$ not working enough to conclude there are no solutions?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sec^2x-\tan^2x=1$$
It fails at the solution of this problem. Hence there is no solution, because this identity never fails.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Type `$\sin x`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$` to obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, $\cot x$, respectively.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you. I am new to mathjax.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with what you did. The problem has no solution since, precisely, if $x\in\mathbb R$ is such that both $\tan(x)$ and $\sec(x)$ are defined, then $\sec(x)=\tan(x)\iff\sin(x)=1$. But at those numbers $x$ for which $\sin(x)=1$, $\tan(x)$ and $\sec(x)$ are undefined.

Comment: Are you sure that the relation $\sec(x)=\tan(x)\iff\sin(x)=1$ is correct (in my opinion an equality between undefined values makes no sense).

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: In my opinion it is much better, though I would prefer the chain $\cos x\ne 0\implies \sin x=1\implies \cos x =0$.